# how to know whether event.target is an image or not using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Jquery datatable and it has a column under which the images are listed. I have added and event listener for click on the table row. I just want to know whether the user clicked on the cell that has image or not, something like we do for check boxes as

```
if (  $(event.target).is(':checkbox') ){
}.
```

When I inspect   `event.target` in the code, it is coming as below:

```
<img src='contactImages/attachmentImage.png' <img>
```

Any clue on how to verify whether the event.target is an image or not?

Comment: That's perfect !!. I would have opted your solution as correct answer if you added it in the answer part.

Comment: I couldn't see any reason for down-voting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass *img* tag to the function as parameter:

```
$(event.target).is('img')
```

```js
$('img').click(function(event){
  if ($(event.target).is('img')){
    console.log('Element is an image');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src='contactImages/attachmentImage.png'> <img>
```

You can also use the [`nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName) property of [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target):

```js
$('img').click(function(event){
  if (event.target.nodeName == 'IMG'){
    console.log('Element is an image');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src='contactImages/attachmentImage.png'> <img>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.